# How to redirect a domain to a facebook page directly

Tags: facebook, redirect

When I try to redirect my domain http://styleandstuff.pl directly to a Facebook fun page but due to security restrictions it redirects me to "go to Facebook page". I know it's possible because there are some domains that go directly to fb pages like [fapopedia.pl](http://fapopedia.pl). Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site is trying to render Facebook in an iFrame. Looking at your page's source, the Facebook site is loading in the background, but the browsers I tested this on (FF and Chrome) are loading the `noframes` content. I'm not sure if this is a bug, or a Facebook "feature" to make sure their site isn't framed.

The working example you cite uses a http 301 redirect to their Facebook page. You can set this up in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thanks! If someone would ever need that: 
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 2):

Create .htaccess file in your page root directory, chmod 644 it and write in it:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(.+) [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) http://redirecttodomain.com [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(.+) [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) http://redirecttodomain.com [R=301,L]
```